# Start Javascript after submitting my form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary growl-type" data-type="success">Show Success Growl</button>
```

With this Button I open this:

```
<script>
$("vpanmeldung").submit(function() {

    $('.growl-type').live ('click', function (e) {
        $.msgGrowl ({
            type: 'success'
            , title: 'Partner eroflgreich angelegt'
            , text: 'Der Vertriebspartner wurde erfolgreich im System angelegt. Sie können diesen nun in der Übersicht Ihrer Vertriebspartner aktivieren.'
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

But now I want to open it when I sent an form and not by click on the button.
What I must do?

Comment: So you want to open the msqGrowl when you submit the form? Is this correct? In your code I see that you are opening the popup on click .growl-type

Comment: Have you built a form? How do you send the values and where? Are you using php?

Comment: Note that 'live' is deprecated in the latest jquery build. By the way give us more information

Comment: Yes I want to open it, wenn I sent the form.

My Form is like this...
<form id="anmeldung" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

What I must change?

Comment: Then i would suggest that you use php instead of javascript since you have to make the check on the server side anyways.

Comment: Or how can I change it. From click to show if the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you want to open the growl popup exactly when the form is submitted.

In this case you should remove the button click event and place the growl popup init into the form submit event, like this:

```
$("#anmeldung").on('submit', function(ev) {

    // If you want to skip the page redirect you should prevent the event
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.msgGrowl({
        type: 'success'
        , title: 'Partner eroflgreich angelegt'
        , text: 'Der Vertriebspartner wurde erfolgreich im System angelegt. Sie können diesen nun in der Übersicht Ihrer Vertriebspartner aktivieren.'
    });
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hmm I tried this but it doesn't work by me. Must I put it to a special place?

<script>
$(function() {
 
 $("#anmeldung").on('submit', function() {
    $.msgGrowl ({
        type: 'success'
        , title: 'Partner eroflgreich angelegt'
        , text: 'Der Vertriebspartner wurde erfolgreich im System angelegt. Sie können diesen nun in der Übersicht Ihrer Vertriebspartner aktivieren.'
     });
 });
});
</script>

Comment: This does not guarantee that the form submit was successful. It just gives the message as soon as someone clicks the button. Properly, it should have a server side check before showing any success messages.

Comment: @Whistletoe: TrivoxX hasn't asked how to notify the user that the form was submitted successful. He asked how can he show the popup when the form is submitted!

Comment: Yes I make a validation with my formfields. Better is, when I could integrate it in the echo from the success message or so... So Whistletoe was not realy wrong.

Comment: @TrivoXx the <script> .. </script> tags must be after your form. For the jquery form submit event to work the form must already be created in the document. So create the form <form> ... </form> and then place the JS code <script> .. </script>

Comment: My Submit button: <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><i class="icon-ok" style="margin-right:5px;"></i> Submit</button>

Comment: I also saw that in your question that the id of the form differs from the one in your comment to the question. Please check again that the form id is equal to the id used in the JS code.

Comment: Ok thanks now it works... Can I also change it to a way that the form realy is submitted and then make it. Because now I get it also when the validation is failed.

Can I integrate it anyway to the success echo?

Comment: Since you already have jQuery you could use $.post to send your form data to your php script. More details here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ Scroll down for examples :)

Comment: I find the solution from Whistletoe not bad. But how I must change the function to work?

Like this?

<script>
function callback() {

    // If you want to skip the page redirect you should prevent the event
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.msgGrowl({
        type: 'success'
        , title: 'Partner eroflgreich angelegt'
        , text: 'Der Vertriebspartner wurde erfolgreich im System angelegt. Sie können diesen nun in der Übersicht Ihrer Vertriebspartner aktivieren.'
})};
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function test()
        {
            alert('test');
        }

        <?php

            if( [check if submit was successful] )
            {
                echo 'test();';
            }

        ?>

    </script>
</head>
```

You could use `echo '<script>test();'</script>;` somewhere else on the page as long as it comes *after* the javascript function. Otherwise you will have an "function undefined" error.

Comment: Must I do it so?

<script>
function callback() {
$("#anmeldung").on(function(ev) {

    // If you want to skip the page redirect you should prevent the event
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.msgGrowl({
        type: 'success'
        , title: 'Partner eroflgreich angelegt'
        , text: 'Der Vertriebspartner wurde erfolgreich im System angelegt. Sie können diesen nun in der Übersicht Ihrer Vertriebspartner aktivieren.'
    });
})};
</script>

and echo '<script>callback();</script>'; ?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I also tried <script>
function callback() {

    // If you want to skip the page redirect you should prevent the event
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.msgGrowl({
        type: 'success'
        , title: 'Partner eroflgreich angelegt'
        , text: 'Der Vertriebspartner wurde erfolgreich im System angelegt. Sie können diesen nun in der Übersicht Ihrer Vertriebspartner aktivieren.'
})};
</script> but it also doesn't work.